# Need help in database design

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

I have data in country table like this

```
ID      Country
1       US
2       ARG
3       IND
```

In the above table, ID is the primary key. I need to create another affected country table like this

```
Country    Affected_country
 1             ARG
 1             IND
 2             US
```

In the above table, Country column and Affected_country column together are primary key. Country column in affected country is the foreign key to ID column in country table.

Is this right way to design the database?

Comment: If you're using ISO 3166 3-letter country codes, `US` should be `USA`.  If you're using ISO 3166 2-letter country codes, `IND` should be `IN` and `ARG` should be `AR`.  Either way works, but you should be consistent (and you should use the standard country codes unless there's a sound reason to do otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to use the same type int for both fields affected country.
In this case you can create 2 foreing keys on field id in table country.

Comment: Thanks Andrej. I will go with Nizet and urs advice which seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that the design of the country table is sub-optimal.  You don't need the ID column (unless you're using a framework of some kind that doesn't realize that you don't need ID columns in every table).  You could use:

Table Country:

- Code (ISO 3166 2-letter code)
- Name (full name for the country)

The code column would be the primary key; the name column would also be unique and would be an alternative key.  If you must have the ID column, the code column would still be an alternative key.

You can use the ISO 3166 3-letter country codes if you prefer, but you should be consistent.  Using a mix of 2-letter and 3-letter codes is sloppy.

The Affected_Country table would have two columns:

- Country
- AffectedCountry

both of which would be foreign key references to the country code in the country table.  The sample data in the affected country table would be:

```
Country   AffectedCountry
US        IN
US        AR
AR        US
```

This makes sense if you know the country codes at all, and is no worse than the original design if you don't know what the country codes mean.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice. I will take care of your advice in the design.you guyz are helping me lot

Answer (score 1):

No. The second column should also be a foreign key pointing to the country primary key:

```
Country    Affected_country
 1             2
 1             3
 2             1
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, there is nothing wrong with that database design. But you may try to explore other alternatives depending on what is the functional requirement, what kind of select or insert queries will run on those tables etc.

One alternative, as suggested by @JBNizet, is to use the country ID in the Affected_country column as well. Another alternative could be to keep affected countries as a comma-separated list in the main country table itself.

Comment: Hehe, no, I'm not. As I said, it depends on what are the functional requirements and the kind of queries / output required. It is not always that the relational design fits best